# List Data Structure that for Fast Index Finding

Tags: data-structures

I need to store a large number of elements in a list-like data structure. The additional requirement is that it should be fast to determine the index for each element at any time. The elements are not sorted, and sorting is not possible.

If a simple array is used, we will have to use a linear search each time the index for an element is queried. This works, but it is a very inefficient solution. Here is the data structure in pseudo code:

```
class IndexList1 {
  Array elements

  getIndex(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i] == e) {
        return i
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  insertAt(e, i) {
    elements.insertAt(e, i)
  }

  removeFrom(i) {
    elements.removeFrom(i)
  }

}
```

A better approach is to map the element to the index either in an internal map or as a field in the element. This way no search is necessary to determine the index of an element. The problem here is that after inserting or removing an element into/from the middle of the list, all indexes after the insertion point have to be updated. For frequent insertions and deletions and a large number of elements this is not very efficient.

In pseudo code the improved data structure looks like this:

```
class IndexList2 {
  Array elements
  Map elementIndexMap

  getIndex(e) {
    return elementIndexMap.get(e)
  }

  insertAt(e, i) {
    elements.insertAt(e, i)
    updateIndicesFrom(i)
  }

  removeFrom(i) {
    elementsIndexMap.delete(elements[i])
    elements.removeFrom(i)
    updateIndicesFrom(i)
  }

  updateIndicesFrom(i) {
    for (; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elementsIndexMap[elements[i]] = i
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a clever list-like data structure for a large number of elements that keeps track of the index for each element, even with many insertions and deletions, in an efficient way? By efficient I mean O(1) for `getIndex()` and something better than O(n) for `insert()` and `remove()`.

Comment: Thanks, added the desired time complexities. Also changed to internal map for clarification.

Comment: One improvement in the second data structure would be to remember the lowest changed index with each call to insert() and remove() and only update the indices from there if getIndex() is called. This will avoid remapping if multiple insert and remove operations take place without calling getIndex() between them.

Comment: Thanks @Magnus, but as I wrote in my question the elements are not sorted and sorting is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to solve this problem is to put the items in some kind of balanced tree (red-black tree, B+tree, skip-list, etc.) with parent pointers, and to label each node in the tree with the size of its subtree.

Then you can find the index of any item by walking up to the root, and adding up the sizes of any subtrees to its left.

It's like an order statistic tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) without sorting the keys.